# How many of these disjunctions can be made simultaneously true by an assignment of truth values to $p, q, r, s$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, propositional-calculus

Here is Prob. 63, Sec. 1.3, in the book *Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications* by Kenneth H. Rossen, 8th edition:

> How many of the disjunctions $p \lor \overline{q} \lor s$, $\overline{p} \lor \overline{r} \lor s$, $\overline{p} \lor \overline{r} \lor \overline{s}$, $\overline{p} \lor q \lor \overline{s}$, $q \lor r \lor \overline{s}$, $q \lor \overline{r} \lor \overline{s}$, $\overline{p} \lor \overline{q} \lor \overline{s}$, $p \lor r \lor s$, and $p \lor r \lor \overline{s}$ can be made simultaneously true by an assignment of truth values to $p$, $q$, $r$, and $s$?

My Attempt:

> Let us first number these disjunctions as follows:
> $$
> \begin{align}
> & 1. \qquad  p \lor \overline{q} \lor s, \\
> & 2. \qquad  \overline{p} \lor \overline{r} \lor s, \\ 
> & 3. \qquad \overline{p} \lor \overline{r} \lor \overline{s}, \\
> & 4. \qquad \overline{p} \lor q \lor \overline{s}, \\
> & 5. \qquad q \lor r \lor \overline{s}, \\
> & 6. \qquad q \lor \overline{r} \lor \overline{s}, \\
> & 7. \qquad \overline{p} \lor \overline{q} \lor \overline{s}, \\
> & 8. \qquad p \lor r \lor s, \\
> & 9. \qquad p \lor r \lor \overline{s}.
> \end{align}
> $$

> Now when $p$ is True, each of the disjunctions in 1., 8., and 9. will be True.

> When $r$ is False, each of the disjunctions in 2., 3., and 6. will be true.

> And, when $s$ is False, each of the disjunctions in 4., 5., and 7. will be true.

> Thus each of our nine disjunctions can be made simultaneously true by the assignment $T$, $F$, and $F$ to $p$, $r$, and $s$, respectively, independently of the truth value assigned to $q$.

> Of course there are other options too such as when $p$ is False and each of $q$, $r$, and $s$ is True, for instance.

Is this the correct and most optimal solution possible to this problem? Or, are there more efficient ways of thinking about it?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, your solution works. I guess I would have done something like:

$$
\begin{align}
& 1. \qquad  p \lor \overline{q} \lor s, \\
& 2. \qquad  \overline{p} \lor \overline{r} \lor s, \\ 
& 3. \qquad \overline{p} \lor \overline{r} \lor \overline{s}, \\
& 4. \qquad \overline{p} \lor q \lor \overline{s}, \\
& 5. \qquad q \lor r \lor \overline{s}, \\
& 6. \qquad q \lor \overline{r} \lor \overline{s}, \\
& 7. \qquad \overline{p} \lor \overline{q} \lor \overline{s}, \\
& 8. \qquad p \lor r \lor s, \\
& 9. \qquad p \lor r \lor \overline{s}.
\end{align}
$$

Look at 8. and 9. If you want both of those to be true, you need $p\lor r$. So I would substitute 8. and 9. with $p\lor r$. Then same for 5. and 6. you can substitute $q\lor \overline s$. For 2. and 3. you get $\overline p\lor \overline r$. Now you have:

$$
\begin{align}
& 1. \qquad  p \lor \overline{q} \lor s, \\
& 2. \qquad  \overline{p} \lor \overline{r}, \\
& 4. \qquad \overline{p} \lor q \lor \overline{s}, \\
& 5. \qquad q \lor \overline{s}, \\
& 7. \qquad \overline{p} \lor \overline{q} \lor \overline{s}, \\
& 8. \qquad p \lor r.
\end{align}
$$

Now if this 5. is true, automatically you get 4. so you can delete 4. You want 2. and 8. both to be true, so $p$ and $r$ have to be one false and the other true. Notice that $r$ appears only in 2. and 8., so you can substitute those with something like $v(r)=1-v(p)$ to indicate that the value of $r$ has to be opposite to the one of $p$.

$$
\begin{align}
& 1. \qquad  p \lor \overline{q} \lor s, \\
& 5. \qquad q \lor \overline{s}, \\
& 7. \qquad \overline{p} \lor \overline{q} \lor \overline{s}, \\
& a.\qquad v(r)=1-v(p).
\end{align}
$$

Now you can do it basically by hand, if $p$ is true then you need both $q\lor\overline s$ and $\overline q\lor \overline s$ to be true, so you need $s$ to be false and you get the quadruple $(1,1,0,0)$ and $(1,0,0,0)$ as possible solutions for $(v(p),v(q),v(r),v(s))$. If instead $p$ is false, you need both $\overline q\lor s$ and $q\lor \overline s$ so you need $v(q)=1-v(s)$ and you get $(0,1,0,1)$ and $(0,0,1,1)$.

So you have four possible assignments that make all nine propositions true. You found the first two but for completeness I guess it's good to see them all. My solution wasn't really different from yours, I just did a bit of algebraic manipulations before examining case by case